# Pass an environment variable to a Custom Builder in Scons

Tags: scons

I have a custom builder as follows

```
my_builder = Builder(action = ['mytool' + env['TESTFLAG'] + ' $SOURCE -o $TARGET')],
                     suffix = '',
                     src_suffix = '.cpp',
                     single_source = True)
env.Append(BUILDERS = {'TestBuilder': my_builder})
```

I would like to pass a different value for `TESTFLAG` each time `TestBuilder` is invoked. Setting the variable each time before a call to TestBuilder doesn't work.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The trick when working with SCons, and in particular when adding new functionality is to remember that it is declarative - you say what you want to happen, and it will work out how (and in what order) it needs to execute actions to make that happen. When you write a Builder, you're specifying actions that will be executed *when the tool needs to be run*.

The problem comes about because the value of `TESTFLAGS` isn't known when you create the builder. In effect, you need a mechanism for delaying when a variable will be evaluated. SCons uses variable substitution to achieve this.

In the `TestBuilder` below, `$TESTFLAG`, `$SOURCE` and `$TARGET` will all be replaced with values when the tool is run.

```
my_builder = Builder(action = 'mytool $TESTFLAG $SOURCE -o $TARGET',
                     suffix = '',
                     src_suffix = '.cpp',
                     single_source = True)
env['TESTFLAG'] = 'default-value'
env.Append(BUILDERS = {'TestBuilder': my_builder})
env.TestBuilder( 'foo.cpp' )
env.TestBuilder( 'bar.cpp', TESTFLAG = 'overridden-value' )
```

Comment: But what if I'm using a generator and not an action?  Can is still be done?